# Why is this instance of threading slower than a list comprehension?

Tags: python, multithreading, list, set, multiprocessing

I have a function that returns the ["support"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning#Support) of a given itemset in a transaction list how often a list of items appears in rows below:
def count(pair_list):

```
def support_tuple(items):
    count = float(sum([1 for row in rows_tuple if (items in row)]))
    supp = count/n_rows
    return (items, supp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
    import multiprocessing as mp

    pairs = [('apple', 'banana'), ('cookie', 'popsicle'), ('candy', 'cookie'), ...]

    # grocery transaction data
    rows_tuple = [{('margarine', 'margarine'), ('citrus', 'semi-finished'), ('bread', 'bread'), ('citrus', 'citrus')}, {('bread', 'fruit'), ('citrus', 'margarine'), ('ready', 'bread'), ('semi-finished', 'fruit'), ('soups', 'margarine'), ('margarine', 'soups')}, {('fruit', 'margarine'), ... }]

    res_list_comprehension = [support_tuple(pair) for pair in pairs]

    threadpool = ThreadPool(mp.cpu_count())
    res_threading = threadpool.map(support_tuple, pairs, chunksize = 100)
```

In reality, `rows_tuple` has length 18000 and `pairs` has length 9000, but my main question is why does a list comprehension outperform threading in this case? Am I missing something completely with threading that would dramatically improve speed?

Comment: Because of the GIL, threads won't improve performance for cpu-bound operations. That means that in this case, you're just adding the overhead of context switching between threads, without any benefits.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, does that mean any sort of parallel processing, e.g. `multiprocessing.Pool` or threading will not give me performance gains?

Comment: If you are using `multiprocessing.dummy` you won't get any benefits, since it is only a wrapper around `threading` but `multiprocessing` itself can run in multiple cores. I do not understand why people keep referring to GIL when talking about `multiprocessing`:  _The multiprocessing package offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads._

Comment: `multiprocessing.Pool` may improve performance, but it may not. If the calculations you're doing in the worker processes aren't expensive, the interprocess-communication overhead required to pass your arguments and results between your main process and your workers could outweigh the gains of parallelizing the calculations. It's easy enough to test it and find out :)

Comment: I'm currently trying `multiprocessing.Pool` with `pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())` and `res = pool.map(support_tuple, pairs)`, but am getting the GIL error: `NameError: name 'rows_tuple' not defined`

Comment: I'm a bit curious why you need to optimize this so badly? Since this a third question you ask about almost the same piece of code. No offense :)

Comment: The whole thing runs in like 25 seconds, so I know it's not a HUGE deal. But I'm genuinely curious about why I can't spin up several processes and do it in 5 seconds as opposed to 25. I'm trying to learn :)

Comment: @GBR24 That error isn't related to the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). That error is happening because you're defining `rows_tuple` inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard, which means its not defined at all in your worker processes. If you define it outside the guard, it should work.